# How to use different version of Elixir runtime for Visual Studio Code extension(ElixirLS) from locally set one(.tool_versions)

Tags: visual-studio-code, elixir, asdf-vm

elixir(1.8.1) and erlang(21.3.5) are set locally via .tool-versions(ASDF) file.

ElixirLS launched using above version of elixir but [it requires higher version](https://github.com/elixir-lsp/elixir-ls#supported-versions).

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function ElixirLS.Utils.OutputDevice.get_opts/0 is undefined (module ElixirLS.Utils.OutputDevice is not available)
    ElixirLS.Utils.OutputDevice.get_opts()
    lib/wire_protocol.ex:33: ElixirLS.Utils.WireProtocol.intercept_output/2
    lib/language_server/cli.ex:6: ElixirLS.LanguageServer.CLI.main/0
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:232: Code.eval_string/3
[Info  - 1:09:58 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function ElixirLS.Utils.OutputDevice.get_opts/0 is undefined (module ElixirLS.Utils.OutputDevice is not available)
    ElixirLS.Utils.OutputDevice.get_opts()
    lib/wire_protocol.ex:33: ElixirLS.Utils.WireProtocol.intercept_output/2
    lib/language_server/cli.ex:6: ElixirLS.LanguageServer.CLI.main/0
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:232: Code.eval_string/3
[Info  - 1:09:59 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function ElixirLS.Utils.OutputDevice.get_opts/0 is undefined (module ElixirLS.Utils.OutputDevice is not available)
    ElixirLS.Utils.OutputDevice.get_opts()
    lib/wire_protocol.ex:33: ElixirLS.Utils.WireProtocol.intercept_output/2
    lib/language_server/cli.ex:6: ElixirLS.LanguageServer.CLI.main/0
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:232: Code.eval_string/3
[Info  - 1:10:00 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function ElixirLS.Utils.OutputDevice.get_opts/0 is undefined (module ElixirLS.Utils.OutputDevice is not available)
    ElixirLS.Utils.OutputDevice.get_opts()
    lib/wire_protocol.ex:33: ElixirLS.Utils.WireProtocol.intercept_output/2
    lib/language_server/cli.ex:6: ElixirLS.LanguageServer.CLI.main/0
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:232: Code.eval_string/3
[Info  - 1:10:02 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function ElixirLS.Utils.OutputDevice.get_opts/0 is undefined (module ElixirLS.Utils.OutputDevice is not available)
    ElixirLS.Utils.OutputDevice.get_opts()
    lib/wire_protocol.ex:33: ElixirLS.Utils.WireProtocol.intercept_output/2
    lib/language_server/cli.ex:6: ElixirLS.LanguageServer.CLI.main/0
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:232: Code.eval_string/3
[Error - 1:10:02 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will not be restarted.
```

Can I make the extension to use global version(set by ASDF) of elixir?

Comment: is there a problem upgrading OTP version in your local environment?

Comment: I want to keep local version as it is, because .tool-versions file's in git repo.

Answer (score 1):

Before running anything that requires Elixir (e.g. in your case VScode and ElixirLS), you can override the elixir version by setting a temporary shell version - `asdf shell elixir <elixir version you want>`. This sets a shell environment variable that the asdf shim will read when running that will override the version set in `.tool-versions`. Of course you'll need to have the version of Elixir you want to use already installed on your system and launch everything from the shell that has the environment variable set.

Alternatively you can try something like this to disable reading of `.tool-versions` files entirely - https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf/issues/870#issuecomment-780862765